# extract values from the command output in c

Tags: c, linux, awk, sed

I am running this command

```
cat /proc/devices/memory/events/pcie0_read
```

in my code (c application). This is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main()

{

system(" cat /proc/devices/memory/events/pcie0_read ");

}
```

and the output of this command is

fidt=0x12,dtw=0x33,id=0x67

I want to extract only values from the command output using same c application.

I want to extract only 0x336712 only and save this value in an variable from the above command output.

for ex:

```
char var[100] or unsigned int var;
```

After extracting from command output I should get it,

```
var=0x336712
```

How do I do that???

Comment: On a POSIX system (such as linux) use [`popen()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html) instead of `system()`.

Comment: use `strtok()`, first with `,` as delimiter, then `=`.

Comment: According to the tags you seem to think of a solution based on running `awk` and/or `sed`. Of course it is possible to extract values this way, but this can be easily implemented in C without running external programs. The declaration of the variable `var` as a `char` array doesn't match the assignment of a hexadecimal integer value. Please [edit] your question and add more details what you want to do with the values. Do you need at the end a string `"0xff2006"` or an (`unsigned`) `int` value `0xff2006` or individual values `0x06`, `0x02`, `0xff`?

Comment: Not necessary char array.I just need to extract 0xff2006 from the command output and store it in an variable and variable can be unsigned int.....whatever you said is correct ...I need unsigned int value 0xff2006

Comment: Please [edit] your question and **add all requested information or clarification to the question**. Don't use comments for this purpose. Explaining some background about what you want to do with the resulting value might help us to suggest the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you really need to run external commands, you may want to read the `/proc/...` directly just like any ordinary files. Also, [fscanf](https://man.dev/man/3/fscanf) function is quite versatile enough to avoid complicated string parsing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
        unsigned int fidt, dtw,id;

        FILE *f = fopen("/proc/devices/memory/events/pcie0_read", "r");
        fscanf(f, "fidt=%x,dtw=%x,id=%x", &fidt, &dtw, &id);
        fclose(f);

        printf("output: 0x%x\n", (id << 32) | (dtw << 16) | fidt);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: printf("output: 0x%02x%02x%02x\n", portid&0xFF, evtype&0xFF, event&0xFF);

Comment: The file name and the resulting data has been changed in the question, so the answer should be adapted.